# Using a object in methods of other objects

Tags: php, class, methods

in this case I create a sqlite3 object in the main file of my script:

```
$db = new sqlite3('file.sqlite');
```

now I need to access the sqlite file in different other methods of other classes.
But what is the best way to access the object there?

Create every time a new object?

Use in the methode global?

```
global $db;
```

Or deliver it as argument?

```
$object = new exampleClass($db);
```

Comment: The final one is referred to as *dependency injection*, and is what you should use.

Comment: and then save it to a property? Or deliver it evry time when I request a public method?

Comment: Assign it to a property in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely:

```
$object = new exampleClass($db);
```

Or it is possible to use a `registry` class to store objects and then retrieve them when needed.  Someone will chime in that this is a bad practice, but oh well:

```
$object = Registry::get('db');
```

Comment: Yes definitely better than global or creating it again and again. +1 But however, there are also other ways to do it. I like symfony2's attempt on this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: and then save it to a property? Or deliver it evry time when I request a public method?

Comment: Why should the second attempt being bad practice? Looks basically good

Comment: If you instantiate an object that needs the `$db` to query, update, etc then in the `__construct` you can set `$this->db = Registry::get('db');`

Comment: Same with passing `$db` into `exampleClass`.  Either way `exampleClass($db)` constructor would assign `$db` to a property of `exampleClass`.