# What's the difference between Laravel automatic injection and manually specifying the dependencies in the constructor body?

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

I'm using a Repository pattern in my Laravel project. This pattern is not really explained in the official documentation, [except for this snippet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#automatic-injection):

> You may type-hint a repository defined by your application in a controller's constructor. The repository will automatically be resolved and injected into the class.

This is my code, in accordance with the documentation:

```
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(CategoriesRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }
```

I've type-hinted the CategoriesRepository so it gets automatically loaded by the Service Container.

However, if I directly create a new instance of the CategoriesController class (without using the Service Container), I have to specify that I need a new instance of the CategoriesRepository too, like this:

```
$example = new CategoriesController(new CategoriesRepository());
```

Now, let's suppose I write the following code.

```
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->repo = new CategoriesRepository();
    }
```

This way, I don't have to load the class through the Service Container, nor call it by passing a new instance of CategoriesRepository as the argument, because it's automatically created inside of the constructor.

So, my question is: would this be bad practice? **What's the difference between type-hinting as a parameter and creating a new instance inside of the constructor?**

Comment: Here's one voice on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056856/oop-dependencies-dependency-injection-vs-registry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the beauty of dependency injection:

**Complex initialization**

```
class MyController {

     public function __construct(A $a) { }
}

class A {
     public function __construct(B $b) { }
}
class B {
     public function __construct(C $c) { }
}

class C {
     public function __construct(D $d) { }
}
class D {
     public function __construct() { }
}
```

Now you can ask laravel to create that class for you e.g:

```
$controller = make(MyController::class);
```

or you can do:

```
$controller = new MyController(new A(new B(new C(new D())))));
```

In addition you can specify more complex rules on how to create the variables:

```
app()->bind(D::class, function ($app) {
       $d = new D();
       $d->setValueOfSomething($app->make(AnotherClass::class));
       return $d;
});
```

**Testing**

That's one advantage of dependency injection over manual creation of things. Another is unit testing:

```
    public function testSomeFunctionOfC() {
        $this->app->bind(D::class, function () {
               $dMock = $this->createMock(D::class);
        });
        $c = make(C::class);
    }
```

Now when you create C the class D will be the mocked class instead which you can ensure works according to your specification.